# Calculating sum of differences from each group

Tags: sql-server, database

I have the following table:

```
Sensor | building | Date_time  | Current_value
1      |   1      | 20.08.2017 |   20
1      |   1      | 21.08.2017 |   25
1      |   1      | 22.08.2017 |   35
2      |   1      | 20.08.2017 |  120
2      |   1      | 21.08.2017 |  200
2      |   1      | 22.08.2017 |  210
3      |   2      | 20.08.2017 |   20
3      |   2      | 21.08.2017 |   25
3      |   2      | 22.08.2017 |   85
5      |   2      | 20.08.2017 |  320
5      |   2      | 21.08.2017 |  400
5      |   2      | 22.08.2017 |  410
```

The sensor ID is assumed to be unique, as is the building ID.

I need to calculate the total value for each building for any given timeframe by subtracting the MIN value from the MAX value for each sensor, then group the sum by each building.

In the above sample it would be

```
Sensor 1: (35 - 20)=15
Sensor 2: (210-120)=90
Building 1 = 15+90 = 105
(...)
Building 2 = 65+90 = 155
```

Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Total means you are adding stuff. What you describe though is the sum of *sensor differences* per building

Comment: I need to add the individual differences, as a building has several sensors. I'll gladly rephrase the topic to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking how to calculate the difference between min and max values per sensor, then *aggregate* the differences per building.

```
with diffs as (
    SELECT Building,Sensor, MAX(Current_Value)-MIN(Current_Value) as diff
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY Building, Sensor 
)
SELECT Building,sum(diff)
FROM diffs
GROUP BY Building
```

If you want to restrict the time period, you'll have to do so inside the CTE :

```
with diffs as (
    SELECT Building,Sensor, MAX(Current_Value)-MIN(Current_Value) as diff
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE Date_Time between @start and @end
    GROUP BY Building, Sensor 
)
SELECT Building,sum(diff)
FROM diffs
GROUP BY Building
```

You can convert this query into a user defined function that can be used in other queries :

```
create function fn_TotalDiffs(@start datetime2(0), @end datetime2(0))
returns table 
as 
Return (
    with diffs as (
        select Building,Sensor, MAX(Current_Value)-MIN(Current_Value) as diff
        from SomeTable
        Group by Building, Sensor 
    )
    select Building,sum(diff) as Total
    from diffs
    Group by Building
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option  using window function min/max over()

**Example**

```
Select Building
      ,Total  = sum(R1)
 From (
        Select Distinct
               Building
              ,R1 = max([Current_value]) over (Partition By Building,Sensor) 
                   -min([Current_value]) over (Partition By Building,Sensor) 
         From YourTable
         Where Date_time between @Date1 and @Date2
      ) A      
 Group By Building
```

**Returns**

```
Building    Total
1           105
2           155
```